# Django[ TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'choice' ] Happening when adding a choice in my model

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model that is a radar, and it needs to have 4 possible modes. I followed the documentation on the django website (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#choices). However I am still getting an error. I will post my model file down below. If you think I might need to post any other code let me know.

```
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.

class Radar(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    SCAN = "SC"
    ON = "ON"
    OFF = "OF"
    STANDBY = "ST"
    MODE_CHOICES = (
        (SCAN, "scan"),
        (ON, "on"),
        (OFF, "off"),
        (STANDBY, "standby"),
    )
    mode_choice = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choice=MODE_CHOICES,
        default=OFF,
    )

    ip_address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    start_azimuth_angle = models.FloatField(default=0)
    end_azimuth_angle = models.FloatField(default=0)
    azimuth_scan_speed = models.FloatField(default=0)
    azimuth_increment = models.FloatField(default=0)

    start_elevation_angle = models.FloatField(default=0)
    end_elevation_angle = models.FloatField(default=0)
    elevation_scan_speed = models.FloatField(default=0)
    elevation_increment = models.FloatField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        string = 'RadarID : %s   ip: %s ' % (self.id, self.ip_address)
        return string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your code:

instead of `choice`, the correct argument is `choices`

```
mode_choice = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=MODE_CHOICES,
        default=OFF,
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

option for using choices with CharField is choices. change choice to choices. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#choices